# Allowing non-admin to create order in spree backend

Tags: spree, cancancan, spree-auth-devise

I would like to create a role which is not the admin that can create order in the spree backend, but I couldn't find the combination of actions that I need to activate for that user. I tried adding the default user permission and allow role to `:manage` Order, LineItem, Product, Variant to no success. Right now the role can create new order, but when I search for product to add to cart, the API controller would not allow it.

**Update**:
I try disabling the authentication for the API `Spree::Api::Config[:requires_authentication] = false` and it solve the problem. So it's definitely a problem with API authentication.

I am using `solidus` which is a fork of `spree 2.4`

```
can_be_like_customer
can :manage, Spree::Order
can :manage, Spree::LineItem
can :manage, Spree::Product
can :manage, Spree::Variant

  def can_be_like_customer
    can :display, Spree::Country
    can :display, Spree::OptionType
    can :display, Spree::OptionValue
    can :create, Spree::Order
    can [:read, :update], Spree::Order do |order, token|
      order.user == user || order.guest_token && token == order.guest_token
    end
    can :display, Spree::Product
    can :display, Spree::ProductProperty
    can :display, Spree::Property
    can :create, Spree.user_class
    can :display, Spree::State
    can :display, Spree::Taxon
    can :display, Spree::Taxonomy
    can :display, Spree::Variant
    can :display, Spree::Zone
  end
```

Log from terminal

```
Processing by Spree::Api::VariantsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"q"=>{"product_name_or_sku_cont"=>"bag"}, "token"=>"", "in_stock_only"=>"true", "_"=>"1447839886731"}
  Spree::User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" WHERE "spree_users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_users"."spree_api_key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["spree_api_key", ""]]
  Rendered /Users/harins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/solidus_api-1.0.2/app/views/spree/api/errors/must_specify_api_key.v1.rabl (0.7ms)
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1778ms (Views: 1775.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override spree ability and add your role condition in initialize method. in that method add following code

```
# for orders
can :admin, Order
can [:modify, :display], Order
can [:create, :cart], Order
can [:admin, :display, :modify], LineItem
can [:admin, :display, :modify], Adjustment
can [:admin, :display, :modify], Payment
can [:admin, :display, :modify], ReturnAuthorization
can [:admin, :display, :modify], CustomerReturn

# for products

can :admin, Product
can [:modify, :display, :stock], Product
can :create, Product
can [:admin, :manage], Image
can [:admin, :manage], Variant
can [:admin, :manage], ProductProperty
can [:admin, :modify], OptionType
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the admin user I created did not have an API generated. Had to go to that user in the admin section and generate an API key using the superadmin account (spree@example.com).